# Loaded object in ActionScript3 with higher FPS

Tags: actionscript-3, swfloader, frame-rate

How can I load a swf in ActionScript 3 with a higher fps than the instance doing the loading with Loader?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see this question quite a bit,

Unfortunately I have to tell you there is no way to play an externally loaded SWF at a different frame rate than the one doing the loading. There is only ever one stage instance (the one in the parent SWF). When you load another external SWF it is treated like any other MovieClip in the display list.

Tyler.

Comment: Exactly... you could however change the main movie's framerate in runtime with Stage.frameRate http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate

Comment: This sucks.  It should be able to compensate for externally loaded movies with a lower frame rate than the stage without affecting the stage's frame rate, especially for movies loaded that have embedded video or that have sync to stream enabled for audio.